# RSpec with reusable method for shared examples context

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'd like to include one method in many RSpec shared examples overriding default context method:

```
describe 'Links' do
  describe EditLink do
    it_behaves_like 'update association service', :link do
      def create_association(params, user_symbol)
        AddLink.new(user_symbol).(params)
      end
    end
  end

  describe DeleteLink do
    it_behaves_like 'delete association service', :link do
      def create_association(params, user_symbol)
        AddLink.new(user_symbol).(params)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Is there any way to extract `create_association` and pass it inside shared examples so that it will override default method in shared context without creating those `do ... end` blocks and copy-pasting this method inside every `it_behaves_like`?

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do this with [RSpec helper methods](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/helper-methods).

Add a module with the extracted method somewhere, eg. `spec/support/helpers.rb`:

```
module Helpers
  def create_association(params, user_symbol)
    AddLink.new(user_symbol).(params)
  end
end
```

Make sure this is required in `rails_helper.rb`. Typically anything under `spec/support` is required when using the default RSpec setup.

RSpec needs to be configured to extend shared example groups with the module. This can be done in the `rails_helper.rb` configuration section:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.extend Helpers
end
```

Then the method can be called from within the shared example block:

```
it_behaves_like 'delete association service', :link do
  create_association(params, user_symbol)
end
```

The docs explain other options for limiting the module to specific groups.

To use the helper in normal examples (i.e. outside of shared examples) you need to `include` instead of (or in addition to) `extend`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Helpers
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't working at all. What I'm trying to do is to override method in shared context, which is already there. `config.include Helpers` can't do that, because even when I do `config.include Helpers`, and remove this `do ... end` block, the original method from shared context is being called.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Could you show the code for the method definition that is to be overridden?

Comment: It's included in my question.

Comment: OK, but where is that method defined? In the shared example? In a library?

Comment: In shared examples. In `it_behaves_like 'update association service'` I'd like to override it.

Comment: So if I understand, you define `create_association` in a shared context, include that context, then you want to override the implementation of `create_association` in certain examples. Is that correct?

Comment: Right! And I don't wan't to reimplement it in every shared context where it should be overridden, bot just include it somehow there.

Comment: It *might* work if you call `self.extend Helpers` immediately before the call to the overridden method. Slightly better since you don't have to define the method more than once, but you still need to extend each example, which is klunky. Perhaps there is another approach? Maybe use a different tag for the examples which should override, then add logic in the shared context to use a different method based on the value of the tag.

Comment: I tried almost all cases and none of them works.. I'll leave it as is, it's not much pain, just wanted to have cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

First, a note: If your `create_association` override is the same for both those examples, and they're both under the same outer context as in your sample code, you don't have to declare it twice -- just declare it in the outer context:

```
describe 'Links' do
  def create_association(params, user_symbol)
    AddLink.new(user_symbol).(params)
  end

  describe EditLink do
    # ... (etc.)
  end

  describe DeleteLink do
    # ... (etc.)
  end
end
```

Second: I haven't figured out how to override shared example methods (I still suspect there's a way, something at the method call site that will make it resolve to the re-defined version, but I'm too new to Ruby to have figured it out), but I did find the following workaround:

```
RSpec.shared_examples 'an association service' do
  def create_association(params, user_symbol)
    if defined? create_association_override
      create_association_override
    else
      # ...whatever the default value is...
    end
  end
end
```

And in the spec:

```
describe 'Links' do
  def create_association_override(params, user_symbol)
    AddLink.new(user_symbol).(params)
  end
  # ...(etc.)
```

It's an ugly way to fake virtual method lookup, and I'll be very surprised if I never hear about a better one, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish is a good approach in general.  It smells like you need to rethink and refactor your RSpec examples. You're going to need to do some error checking to ensure
that all methods you use to create your associations are valid and that any arguments you pass in are likewise error-free.  That introduces brittleness. Additionally, you may be sacrificing readability and thereby increase your maintenance costs.

Nonetheless, I created example code to show how this can be done.  It's not that complicated.

Essentially, you want to accomplish 2 things:

1. have a default `association` that is created by some default method
2. have arguments for a shared_example be optional.
   If you don't pass any arguments to the shared_example, it should just use the default method:
   `it_behaves_like 'update association service'`

   But if you *do* pass in arguments, then use those arguments (the method and parameters, etc.) to create the association:

   `it_behaves_like 'update association service', DeleteLink, :new, []`

   The arguments above are *the class to instantiate*, *the method to use to create your association (which is sent to the class)*, and *the arguments for the method.*  (The arguments would obviously depend on how you wrote your shared example.)

It's just Ruby.  In your shared_example, just check to see if the arguments are nil and then act accordingly.  Here's the basic idea:

```
RSpec.shared_examples 'update association service' do |optional_class, optional_method, parameters|

  let(:assoc) {
    if optional_class.nil? || optional_method.nil?
      default_assoc  # defined prior to this (needs error checking) 
                     #  See the gist for a full example
    else
      optional_class.send(optional_method, *parameters)
    end
  }

  it 'does something with the assoc' do
    expect(assoc.behavior_tested).to eq expected_behavior
  end

end
```

`

Here's how you might use it in your Rspec example group:

```
RSpec.describe 'Links' do

  # set the default method. In the gist, I use a shared_context to do this
  let(:default_assoc) {
      default_class.send(default_method, arg1, arg2)
  }


  describe 'AddLink' do

    # Since no arguments are passed to this shared example,
    # it will use 'default_assoc' in the shared_example.
    it_behaves_like 'update association service'

  end

  describe 'EditLink' do

    # Override how the association is created in the shared_example
    # by passing in arguments that are used to create it:
    it_behaves_like 'update association service', MySpecialAssocClass, :special_create_method, [arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4]

  end
end
```

A full working example with copious comments is in my gist on github: [weedySeaDragon -  rspec-shared-context-examples-optional.rb](https://gist.github.com/weedySeaDragon/af839c94ee7de016b02847b1dc1f4795)